# Dropdown menu js

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Есть ссылка 
`<a href="#" onclick="js"><img="path"></a>`
для открытия меню в мобильной версии сайта, проблема в том что при нажатии на ссылку перекидывает на страницу с url заканчивающийся /#, а нужно, чтобы просто открывались меню. Как сделать пустую ссылку?

Comment: Вам обязательно использовать `<a>` ? Можно также обрабатывать клик на `<span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в функции запретить действие по умолчанию

```
<a href="#" onclick="menu_open(e)"><img="path"></a>

<script>
function menu_open(e)
{
   //код

   //запрещаем переход по ссылке
   e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```